# gembox spreadsheet Calculate method not available

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, gembox-spreadsheet

GemBox Spreadsheet (https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) documentation indicates a Calculate method is available at the excel file level object. However this Calculate method is missing when you reference the main library. Do I need a different library for this. There is nothing about it on their site.

Comment: Is the calculate method a macro inside the Excel file?

Comment: I was using an older version which doesn't have the feature. Latest version is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an older version which didn't have this feature. Latest version has it.